# Table as child of button element html. MVC razor view

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I would like to have table element displayed in button element. After clicking the button I want to submit the form with data from the table. I did it in this way:

```
<form>
    <button type="submit" class="ui-btn">
        @Html.Partial("Partial1")
    </button>
</form>
```

I validated my page using: `https://validator.w3.org` and I got following error:

```
Element table not allowed as child of element button in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
```

So I cannot use a table as a child of a button at all? What should I do to achieve similar effect without using this structure?

Partial view:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>First</th>
    <th>Second</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Firsta</th>
    <th>Second</th>
</tr>
```

Comment: "to achieve similar effect" - What effect is that?  Why would you want *an entire table* on a single button?  What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: what about an hyperlink? you can make a link's class the SAME as a button, visually

Comment: with hyperlink I would have to use javascript to submit form. I'm not js expert so I want to avoid it.

Comment: table inside a button. That's new.

Comment: If you want to submit table data, you do not need to embed the table inside button. You can make a post request and all the form data you can capture in your controller.

Comment: What if I have a list of tables and corresponding forms?

Comment: Still what ever you have you will eventually be wrapping everything to a ViewModel class which corresponds to that UI. Once you have a proper ViewModel to hold all the data, you job should be to iterate through the object or whatever. I am beginner but just telling my ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of making a table element a child of a button element is bizarre. I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve but how about you use the good old method of making the table element a child of  form element instead.

See example here: https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/tables.html

Comment: I want to have button with table displayed in it so I can click on it and move to action method operating on data from the button

Comment: Even if you keep the button outside, you can achieve that.

Comment: How should I do it? When I move table outside the button I get empty clickable button with unclickable table below it.